# Textview resets to old value when scrolling up

Tags: android-listview, textview, android-adapter, android-scrollview, android

I am creating a list view. I am populating the listview using custom adapter. In my listview there is a text view widget. When I reset the value of that text view it displays fine. Then, I scroll down to get new values into the listView.  But when I scroll up the text view widget resets back to the old populated value.
How can I retain the new value set by me persistently? 
Here is the code of my listview adapter class where I populate the values to my listview. I am clicking on imageview in the listview that fires the event to set new text value to the text view widget in the list view.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CommentInfo> {


    public MyListAdapter()
    {
        super(Comment.this, R.layout.listview_xml, myComments);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        itemView = convertView;

        if(itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_xml, parent, false);

        }
        CommentInfo currentComment = myComments.get(position);


        TextView tvLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikes);
        tvLikes.setText(currentComment.likes);

        ImageView ivLikes = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
        ivLikes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                likePosition = position;                    
                TextView tvlikes1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikes);
                // Here, i will get the correct value from DB and set it.
                // I am setting 999 for sample purpose
                tvlikes1.setText("999");
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

I reset the value of listview's text view by getting convertView value in getView() argument in my above adapter class and accessing my listview's textview widget through it. Then, i set it to value 999 (for example purpose). Now, I scroll down to get more new listView items. But, on scrolling up the new value (999) that i set to the old item disappears.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Why do you have to use findViewById() to find your TextView again inside the OnClick() method. You can reuse tvLikes (make it final though) instead of tvLikes1.

Comment: Tony, I tried with tvLikes itself. Yes I need not use findViewById(). But it does not solve my problem of new values resetting back to oldvalue in text view widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a test myself. The ListView adapter will always take the values from the myComments list, so in order to update the TextView as you want, you have to do like this:

```
ivLikes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            likePosition = position;                    
            myComments.get(position).setLikes("999");//Assume that your CommentInfo's likes is a string.
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```